# Install Apache Server HTTPD on Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I'm trying to install `Apache Server` on my Ubuntu for using a web page made in `PHP`.
I downloaded `pcre`, `apr` and `apr-util` and I configured, maked and make install all of them.

Then, when I came back to the Apache folder, the following command

```
sudo ./configure --prefix=/home/test/Apache/srclib/apr-util 
                 --with-apr=/home/test/Apache/srclib/apr 
                 --with-pcre=/home/test/Apache/pcre 
                 --with-included-apr
```

succeded.

Even the command

```
sudo make
```

succeded. But, when I type sudo make install, I got the following error:

```
Makefile:79: recipe for target 'install' failed
make[2]: *** [install] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/test/Apache/srclib/apr-util'
/home/test/Apache/build/rules.mk:75: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/test/Apache/srclib'
/home/test/Apache/build/rules.mk:75: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Please, could you give me any tip? Thank you

Comment: Possibly better asked on https://serverfault.com/?

Comment: why not just use the pre-built package? Or are you trying to learn about compiling?

Comment: Sure you sudoed when doing install? Smells of permission issues.

Comment: If you mean the package in ubuntu repository, I can't access on Internet in my computer where Ubuntu is installed so I'm trying to do that manually.

Comment: Is version? 2.4.?

Comment: You claim you downloaded the source (pcre etc), so presumably you can download things somehow. Therefore you can download the package files in advance the same way . The online docs for the package repo will tell you the dependencies you need as well.

Comment: @ficuscr yes, httpd-2.4.27.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `apr` and `apr-util` versions needed by Apache 2.4.x are missing?. Or maybe you just need the `-dev` packages?

```
cd /usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.20/srclib
curl --remote-name http://archive.apache.org/dist/apr/apr-1.5.2.tar.gz
curl --remote-name http://archive.apache.org/dist/apr/apr-util-1.5.4.tar.gz
tar -xzvf apr-1.5.2.tar.gz
tar -xzvf apr-util-1.5.4.tar.gz
mkdir apr
mkdir apr-util
mv apr-1.5.2/ apr
mv apr-util-1.5.4/ apr-util
cd ..
```

Then compile with

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache-2.4.20 --with-included-apr
```

Good resource: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/install.html
Here is what they say about APR and APR-Util:

> APR and APR-Util Make sure you have APR and APR-Util already installed
>   on your system. If you don't, or prefer to not use the system-provided
>   versions, download the latest versions of both APR and APR-Util from
>   [Apache APR](http://apr.apache.org/), unpack them into /httpd_source_tree_root/srclib/apr and
>   /httpd_source_tree_root/srclib/apr-util (be sure the directory names
>   do not have version numbers; for example, the APR distribution must be
>   under /httpd_source_tree_root/srclib/apr/) and use ./configure's
>   --with-included-apr option. On some platforms, you may have to install the corresponding -dev packages to allow httpd to build against your
>   installed copy of APR and APR-Util.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have apt-get? 
If so, you can use
`sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2-utils libapache2-mod-php5 php5 php-pear php5-xcache php5-mysql php5-curl php5-gd`.
This will install all Apache and PHP software.

Comment: No I don't because my PC (where Ubuntu is installed) can't be connected to Internet.

Comment: @user2896152 do you have ethernet cable?